# Access joined RDD fields in a readable way

Tags: scala, join, tuples, alias, rdd

I joined 2 RDDs and now when I'm trying to access the new RDD fields I need to treat them as Tuples. It leads to code that is not so readable. I tried to use 'type' in order to create some aliases however it doesn't work and I still need to access the fields as Tuples. Any idea how to make the code more readable?

for example - when trying to filter rows in the joined RDD: 
val joinedRDD = RDD1.join(RDD2).filter(x=>x._2._2._5!='temp')

I would like to use names instead of 2,5 etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pattern matching wisely.

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(("John", (28, true)), ("Mary", (22, true)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List(("John", List(100, 200, -20))))
rdd1
  .join(rdd2)
  .map {  
    case (name, ((age, isProlonged), payments)) => (name, payments.sum)
  }
  .filter { 
    case (name, sum) => sum > 0
  }
  .collect()
res0: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((John,280))
```

Another option is using [dataframes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds) abstraction over RDD and writing sql queries.

Comment: I tried to use the map as you wrote, but when I'm trying to use filter function after it, it still handle the fields as tuples and I need to choose ._2 etc.

Comment: @UserIL added `filter {}` function to my example. You can do the same trick with `flatMap`, `reduce`, etc.